# XJC JAXB XSD handling with Java 11

Tags: java, maven, xsd, jaxb

we have a Java 11 based project with maven and within our source code we do have a package with the classes generated by xjc. As soon as we modify the XSD file, we run xjc and copy the classes into our project in order to access the new fields. This is working fine, but as the project grows, we get more and more XSD files and the process of using xjc is not very intuitive. Also xjc is not part of the java 11 Adopt JDK anymore, so we have to use the old java 8 oracle jdk in order to use xjc.

The other option we do have is to use a maven plugin. But I am wondering, if this is working in our project setup. Because the plugin is executed during install phase, the classes will be generated only during this (or whatever phase it is set up). So the classes are only available after running through this phase.

That means if I change an XSD, I copy the new XSD into my project, run mvn install, then update my sources in IntelliJ and then I can access the new fields?

Or is the usual procedure to manage the XSDs in a separate Maven project and configure this project as a dependency in your own main project? As soon as an XSD changes, would I then have a new version of my dependency and would I have to adjust it in the pom.xml?

I am wondering which way makes sense here.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of misconceptions in your question, I'd like to straighten them up:

- you don't need Java 8 to use XJC, as this tool is available on Maven in both the [com.sun.xml.bind](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-xjc) and [org.glassfish.jaxb](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-xjc) groups (the latter one has its dependencies split into many jars). If you want to use JAXB on Java 11 you must include either [jaxb-impl](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl) or [jaxb-runtime](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime) with your software.
- the `jaxb2-maven-plugin` does not run at the `install` phase, but the `generate-sources` phase, which precedes the `compile` phase (cf. [Lifecycles Reference](https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html)).

Whether you decide to run XJC externally or through Maven mostly depends on your development style.

I would split the generated code into another project only if the size of the generated code becomes considerable: e.g. whenever the amount of generated code (which will never be modified manually) started to slow down Eclipse's startup, we migrated it into another project.